# Setting FluentAssertions Expectation on Nullable Enum

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I have the following object (reduced to single property for brevity)

```
public class MyObject {
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and corresponding DTO

```
public class MyDto {
    public MyEnum? MyProperty {get; set;}
}
```

and my mapping is set up such that when string `MyProperty` is empty, the enum is set to null. Now I want to test this using FluentAssertions (there are lots of other properties as well), so I've tried setting the equivalency comparison behavior using the following

```
myDto.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(myObject, opt => opt.Using<MyEnum?>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().Be(null)).When(info => info.SelectedMemberPath.Equals(nameof(MyDto.MyProperty))));
```

But this doesn't work as I get the exception

```
Expected member MyProperty to be a System.String, but found a System.Nullable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've found an edge case here. FluentAssertions treats *enums* and *strings* special, but doesn't handle *nullable enums*. The Using/WhenTypes doesn't support handling properties of different types. The only way to resolve that is to file a change request.

Comment: Sure, will do. The only way I could do it was to create a custom assertion rule, but that seemed a lot of overhead. For now I have excluded the property and asserted after the fact.